# How to solve apt-get command not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get

Hi i am a new with ubuntu and linux,I'm working on baxter robot i have couple problems ..
As i follow the guide steps i have a command that i need to edit a gedit file and write my pc's hostname & ip_address :

```
gedit baxter.sh
```

i did it couple times and when i make the ssh connection when i write :

```
. baxter.sh
```

i get a not :

```
EXITING - Please edit this file, modifying the 'baxter_hostname' variable to reflect Baxter's current hostname.
```

after that i get error on rosrun,apt-get,rosnode commands

```
sudo: apt-get command not found
```

it worked ones when i changed baxter.sh ip address and hostname for first time and that time i didnt get that note, i dont know if that relevant just for more information .
thnx for help

Comment: Try this: `sudo su`, then `which apt-get`. Does that return anything?

Comment: Hi arboreal84 i get this :
which: no apt-get in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc-bin/4.7.3)

Comment: Are you changing the `$PATH` in your script? What does `echo $PATH` show?

Comment: Are you entirely sure you are running Ubuntu? What is the result of `lsb_release -a` ?

Comment: no i dont think so :|
i got this : /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc-bin/4.7.3

Comment: here the guide steps for baxter :
http://sdk.rethinkrobotics.com/wiki/Workstation_Setup

Comment: arboreal84 i get this :
LSB Version: n/a
Distributor ID: Gentoo
Description: Gentoo Base System release 2.2
Release: 2.2
Codename: n/a

Comment: Is it possible that you're trying to run `apt-get` on the robot (running gentoo) instead of your workstation (running Ubuntu)?

Comment: Mark thats why i tried on my workstation it works :)

Answer (score 0):

To fix

```
EXITING - Please edit this file, modifying the 'baxter_hostname' variable to reflect Baxter's current hostname.
```

The first step is to make sure you set the baxter hostname. Per the [baxter sdk guide](http://sdk.rethinkrobotics.com/wiki/Workstation_Setup):

> Baxter's hostname is defaulted as the robot's serial number. The serial number can be located on the back of the robot, next to the power button.
>
> Alternatively, you can find your robot's hostname by plugging a USB keyboard into the back of Baxter and pressing Ctrl+Alt+F3.

You can edit this by opening the file in your terminal (via gedit) or you can navigate to the file using your file browser and change it in a text editor.

To fix

```
sudo: apt-get command not found
```

Checkout some of the [documentation on the baxter.sh script](http://sdk.rethinkrobotics.com/wiki/Baxter.sh).